# How to switch off "Show nested refs" by default

Tags: tortoisegit

Whenever I'm browsing references, I have to disable the checkbox "Show nested refs" manually.

I have not found a switch in the settings dialog. How can I switch off it by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the default value, however, the selected value should be automatically remembered.

There seems to be a bug in TGit 2.5.0, fix will be in TortoiseGit >= 2.5.7.

Bugreport: https://tortoisegit.org/issue/3143

Comment: The last setting is not remembered in my version of (TortoiseGit 2.5.0.0)